# Inserts / Updates Occurring Twice

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
while(1){
    $r = rand(0,9); 
    echo "running...";

    if($current_item  >= $array[$r]['limiter']){
        $foo = $foo;
        $bar = $bar;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (type, hp) VALUES ('$foo', '$bar')");
        echo "done.";
        break 1;
    }
}
```

When I run this I'll get `"running..."` echoed out once or a few times (which is expected) and `"done."` echoed out once, as expected.

Yet two entries will be inserted into the database with different information hinting that the entire if statement ran twice.

Has anybody run into this before? Is there something happening that I'm not seeing here? Any ideas how to fix this?

I have a similar problem with Updates, they too update twice and they're completely separate from a loop.

**Edit:** just to try to clarify,

- `$current_item` does change but in the context of the loop it is constant.
- `$array[$r]['limiter']` references a multidimensional array.
- Neither of these should affect the loop itself, it's just a condition that has to be met to do anything.

Comment: What are you doing here? Where does `$current_item` even change?

Comment: @thatidiotguy $current_item shouldn't change, its just a value like 4 where it is compared against a value in $array[$r]['limiter'], obviously this isn't great way of ding this ..

Comment: @dbf Fair enough, but to ask this question about why it is running multiple times when he is checking a variable against another one that is not explained in the post, makes this basically impossible to answer. It looks like to me that it is almost definitely going to do some random amounts of inserts.

Comment: @thatidiotguy It just has to loop through randomly generated numbers until it finds one that works.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a little the code in order to be able to run it, the code I ran is:

```
    for ($r=0;$r<10;++$r) {
        $array[$r]['limiter'] = $r;
    }
    $current_item = 3;
    $foo = 1;
    $bar = 2;

    while(1){
    $r = rand(0,9); 
        echo "running...";

    if($current_item  >= $array[$r]['limiter']){
        $foo = $foo;
        $bar = $bar;
        echo 'do_query: '."INSERT INTO db (type, hp) VALUES ('$foo', '$bar')";
                echo "done.";
        break 1;
    }
```

And the responce:

1st time: running...do_query: INSERT INTO db (type, hp) VALUES ('1', '2')done.

2nd: running...running...running...do_query: INSERT INTO db (type, hp) VALUES ('1', '2')done.

3rd: running...running...do_query: INSERT INTO db (type, hp) VALUES ('1', '2')done.

So the query executes only once with this code. The problem must be in a piece of code before the while, so it get into the while 2 times.

Comment: Thanks Manolis, I experience the same thing, the echoed portions execute only once. 

I can't think of or see anything in my code that would somehow loop back to run the while loop twice.